# Stop Eclipse Java code completion from tacking on variable type to variable name

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse's Content Assist' Auto Activation, and I love it. But it has one really annoying feature. When I type a variable name, it tacks onto it the variable type. For example:

```
private String name;
```

is automatically changed into

```
private String nameString;
```

Is there a way to disable just this one feature / bug?

I'm using Eclipse Kepler for Mac.